# List value return in C#

Tags: c#

Hello I have compared two list value and if one list value is greater than other I increment that value +1. Similar to Other.

Finally again add that 2 list value one List value and want to return but got error Like these

> solution.cs(42,17): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<int>.Add(int)' has some invalid
>   arguments /usr/lib/mono/4.6-api/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol
>   related to previous error) solution.cs(42,21): error CS1503: Argument`
>   #1' cannot convert `System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' expression
>   to type`int' solution.cs(43,19): error CS1502: The best overloaded
>   method match for `System.Collections.Generic.List<int>.Add(int)' has
>   some invalid arguments /usr/lib/mono/4.6-api/mscorlib.dll (Location of
>   the symbol related to previous error) solution.cs(43,23): error
>   CS1503: Argument`#1' cannot convert
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' expression to type`int'
>   Compilation failed: 4 error(s), 0 warnings

Here is my code

```
int sum_a = 0, sum_b = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
{
    if (a[i] > b[i])
    {
        sum_a++;
    }
    else if (a[i] < b[i])
    {
        sum_b++;
    }
}

List<int> ab = new List<int>();
ab.Add(sum_a);
List<int> ba = new List<int>();
ba.Add(sum_b);

List<int> List = new List<int>();

List.Add(ab);
List.Add(ba);
return List;
//return new List<int>> { sum_a, sum_b };
```

Please help me how to return these list in C#

Comment: What are you trying to do? At the moment you're trying to add two `List<int>` objects to a `List<int>` which (of course) expects numbers. Are you looking for `AddRange`?

Comment: Don't call the list list, you've confused yourself. Change this line 'List<int> List = new List<int>();' to something like 'List<int> chickens = new List<int>();', then you can return chickens, rather than a type.

Comment: you can´t add a list to a list using `Add`. `ab` obviously is a `List<int>`, not a single `int`. You may use `List.AddRange(ab)` instead.

Comment: Also *please*, ***please***, indent your code. How can you read anything the way it is written now? IMHO, coders *should* all have OCD regarding indentation

Answer (score 3):

You cannot insert a `List` in another `List` this way. For that, `AddRange` is used

```
int sum_a=0,sum_b=0;
for(int i=0; i<a.Count; i++)
{
    if(a[i]>b[i])
    {
        sum_a++;
    }
    else if(a[i]<b[i])
    {
        sum_b++; 
    }
}

List<int> ab = new List<int>();
ab.Add(sum_a);
List<int> ba = new List<int>();
ba.Add(sum_b);

List<int> List = new List<int>();
List.AddRange(ab);
List.AddRange(ba);

return List;
```

Comment: Note that naming the variable `List` is still quite a bad choice (as Davesoft pointed out in his comment)

Answer (score 0):

Like @ManishM said, you can't add a List to a List. You can use AddRange in that.

Or based on your scenario, you can just use this:

```
List<int> sumList = new List<int>{ sum_a, sum_b };
```

Comment: Note that naming the variable `List` is still quite a bad choice (as Davesoft pointed out in his comment)